# How to bind into a dropdown values from a json item

Tags: jquery, json

Im a having a long night here

The result of the webservice is in json. However data returned comes with diagnosic data.
How do I get the result set only?

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bkyg23cx/

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://website.com",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total);
            $.each(data.result.records, function (value)
            {
                $("[id$='uxRegion']").append($("<option></option>").val(value.province).html(value.province));
            });
        }
        error: function ajaxError(response)
        {
            alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the problematic json value

```html
{
  "value1": "etetetetete",
  "value2": true,
  "result": {
    "records": [
      {
        "province": "Star world"
      },
      {
        "province": "CNN"
      }
    ],
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "province"
      }
    ],
    "hash": "hash value"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is data.d in the $.each function? I think you have to use `$.each(data.result.records, function...`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `data.result.records` as a local variable `records`, just like below：

```
success: function (data) {
    var records = data.result.records;

    alert('Total results found: ' + records.length);

    $.each(records, function (value) {
        $("[id$='uxRegion']").append($("<option></option>")
                             .val(value.province)
                             .html(value.province));
    });
}
```

And You don't have `total` property on result object, you should use `.length`.

Comment: This looks good but tried applying it, it doesnt work. Im adding the whole html